# The function focus() stops working when I use v-for in Vue for NativeScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a lot of textField and I need to set focus on first by pressing the button.

There is a minimal piece of [code in the playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=P3iu2b&v=2) without **v-for** that works fine.

But when I start to use v-for the program stops to works. There is a minimal piece of [code in the playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=P3iu2b&v=1) with **v-for** and the program crashed if I press the button.

I can't understand where I make a mistake and what I have to do in order to make this code working.

```xml
<template>
    <Page>
        <ActionBar title="Home" />
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout class="home-panel">
                <Label textWrap="true" text="Test focus()!"
                    class="h2 description-label" />

                <TextField v-for="(item, index) in array"
                    v-model="array[index]" :key="'key'+index"
                    :ref="'ref' + index" />

                <Button text="Button" @tap="onButtonTap" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            onButtonTap() {
                console.log("Button was pressed");
                this.$refs["ref0"].nativeView.focus();
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {
                array: ["Hello", "World!"]
            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: How about adding 0 index to this `this.$refs["ref0"][0].nativeView.focus();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `v-for` you may simply assign a static `ref` and access items inside by index.

```
<TextField v-for="(item, index) in array"
     v-model="array[index]" :key="'key'+index" ref="myTxt" />

  .....

  onButtonTap() {
     console.log("Button was pressed");
     this.$refs.myTxt[0].nativeView.focus();
  }
```